# What is the difference between [0] and [:1] in Go?

Tags: go, substring, slice

I split a string by spaces:

```
splstr = strings.Split(str, " ")
```

Then I iterate each word, and look at the first character like this:

```
splstr[i][0] == "#"
```

But I got these errors from that line:

> ... : cannot convert "#" to type uint8
>
> ... : invalid operation: splstr[i][0] == "#" (mismatched types uint8 and string)

But then I spliced it:

```
splstr[i][:1] == "#"
```

And that works. I get why `[:1]` is of type `string`, but why is `[0]` of type `uint8`? (I'm using Go 1.1.)

Comment: `splstr[i][0] == '#'` is valid (note single quotes).  You're indexing the characters of the string, which themselves are not strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the array notation on a string gives access to the string's bytes, as documented in the language spec:

http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types

> A string's bytes can be accessed by integer indices 0 through len(s)-1.

(byte is an alias for uint8)

Answer (score 4):

`[x:x]` (`[:x]` is a form of `[0:x]`) will cut a slice into another slice while `[x]` will retrieve the object at index `x`. The difference is shown below:

```
arr := "#####"
fmt.Println(arr[:1]) // will print out a string
fmt.Println(arr[0]) // will print out a byte
```

If the `string` is converted into `[]byte`:

```
arr := []byte("#####")
fmt.Println(arr[:1]) // will print out a slice of bytes
fmt.Println(arr[0]) // will print out a byte
```

You can try this yourself at http://play.golang.org/p/OOZQqXTaYK